# CSS arrow has glitch when aligned to the right side

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to put a little arrow on a dropdown menu container.

http://jsfiddle.net/0bscj7tm/

```
#nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background: #fff;
}
#nav:after,
#nav:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 20px;
    border: solid transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#nav:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #f00;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
#nav:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 7px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

However, I want the arrow aligned a set number of pixels from the right side. In the `#nav:after, #nav:before` class, I changed `left: 20px` to `right: 20px`, but that makes the border of the arrow too thick on the left side and not visible on the right side: http://jsfiddle.net/vx2Lpt19/1/

Can somebody help me get the arrow to look correctly when aligned 20 pixels from the right side?

Comment: Why are you using negative margins at all? You could simply specify `#nav:before {right:12px;} #nav:after {right:13px;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was just using a technique I saw in a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `margin-left` declarations to `margin-right` under `#nav:before` and `#nav:after`.

Here's what it looks like after that change: http://jsfiddle.net/o4efcsk8/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I can accept this as the answer in 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#nav:before {
border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0);
border-bottom-color: #f00;
border-width: 9px;
margin-right: -2px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background: #fff;
}
#nav:after,
#nav:before {
 content: ' ';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 right: 20px;
 border: solid transparent;
 pointer-events: none;
}
#nav:before {
 border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #f00;
 border-width: 9px;
 margin-right: -2px;
}
#nav:after {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-width: 7px;
 margin-left: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the existing margins on the pseudo-elements didn't seem to do much when I tinkered with them.

However, removing them and just applying a single `-1px` margin seemed to do the trick.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
#nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: #fff;
}
#nav:after,
#nav:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 20px;
  border: solid transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#nav:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #f00;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
#nav:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  content
</div>
```